# PHP jQuery JSON format

Tags: php, jquery, json, format

I have the following code in PHP which returns this JSON code. I can't return the values for "OK" because of the format, I must do some jQuery trick to get it, but I don't want it... Some advice will be appreciated.

**PHP**

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($datBS)) {
    $ahora = $row['servicio'];
    if($ahora != $antes && $n == 1) {
        $ok = array();$ko = array(); $rt = array(); $horas = array();
    }
    if($row['peticion_id'] == 0) {$ok[] = round($row['valor'], 3); $horas[] = $row['hora'];}
    if($row['peticion_id'] == 1) $ko[] = round($row['valor'], 3);
    if($row['peticion_id'] == 2) $rt[] = round($row['valor'], 3);
    $datosBS[$ahora] = array(
            "OK"    =>  $ok,
            "KO"    =>  $ko,
            "RT"    =>  $rt,
            "HORAS" => $horas
    );
    $antes = $ahora;
    $n = 1;
}
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sqlTotalsBS)) {
        $bs[$row['servicio']] = array(
            "SUMOK" => intval($row["OK"]),
            "SUMKO" => intval($row["KO"])
        );
    }
    $banksphere = array_merge_recursive((array)$bs, (array)$datosBS);
    $json = array_merge((array)$banksphere);
    echo json_encode($json);
```

**JSON**

```
{"Servicing":{"SUMOK":923391,"SUMKO":1048,"OK":[184,69,28,14,15,15,0,11,13,0,14,21,19,3,8,0,5,17,13,0,8,30,5,3,13,18,26,24,46,116,342,790,2828,9795,15647,21394,23710,26214,27522,27038,26603,28939,29149,29222,28020,30061,29967,20139,21436,31416,31354,32472,32659,32435,33767,33623,33394,27204,28830,32562,34844,20197,11903,6923,6855,6133,6051,7456,7842,8366,9271,10127,10301,9845,9616,8391],"KO":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,4,9,17,20,11,29,30,35,65,89,56,52,59,26,35,70,39,39,60,28,15,12,27,20,37,20,20,12,8,5,3,8,10,5,12,4,11,9,9,10,11,4],"RT":[0.139,0.171,0.73,0.187,3.667,3.126,0,3.629,7.227,0,4.279,5.967,3.195,2.862,0.883,0,5.441,6.495,0.883,0,1.835,1.656,2.09,0.111,0.35,1.015,1.457,0.829,0.635,0.767,0.534,0.325,0.202,0.172,0.142,0.129,0.125,0.127,0.123,0.125,0.124,0.12,0.122,0.116,0.121,0.114,0.116,0.115,0.116,0.127,0.118,0.128,0.123,0.119,0.12,0.115,0.113,0.114,0.119,0.11,0.104,0.142,0.112,0.139,0.107,0.131,0.149,0.139,0.139,0.133,0.131,0.116,0.109,0.122,0.116,0.113],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Estructurales":{"SUMOK":58088,"SUMKO":453,"OK":[25,12,10,2,16,12,5,11,4,6,10,14,11,7,10,4,7,16,9,6,10,13,9,4,14,10,14,20,33,81,144,366,1562,5956,3671,2251,1976,1960,1600,1656,1475,1396,1473,1567,1412,1486,1553,1198,1046,1655,1636,1743,1711,1550,1417,1340,1562,1312,993,1285,925,790,377,311,286,324,378,486,602,461,542,491,474,450,401,433],"KO":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,2,5,11,11,14,10,9,17,10,9,21,10,10,5,8,14,18,16,33,22,18,19,27,21,29,16,13,11,3,2,1,5,5,1,2,3,3,3,2,4,7],"RT":[0.072,0.888,0.085,0.055,0.063,0.065,0.044,0.113,0.046,0.139,0.08,0.215,0.089,0.134,0.083,0.51,0.242,0.224,0.255,0.126,0.125,0.206,0.343,0.062,0.06,0.229,0.074,0.334,0.08,0.186,0.098,0.113,0.141,0.056,0.091,0.165,0.189,0.187,0.211,0.288,0.248,0.267,0.263,0.279,0.296,0.263,0.257,0.266,0.269,0.303,0.294,0.274,0.275,0.284,0.289,0.287,0.297,0.256,0.591,0.25,0.31,0.382,0.25,0.265,0.1,0.115,0.125,0.123,0.132,0.561,0.172,0.254,0.14,0.106,0.193,0.187],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Movilidad":{"SUMOK":96919,"SUMKO":27,"OK":[1563,1396,1250,1082,825,652,427,416,305,266,205,233,149,203,141,118,148,132,101,86,111,141,205,136,285,405,445,584,736,1159,1047,1333,1406,1627,1828,1978,2393,2533,2351,2445,2182,2346,2068,2067,1900,2187,2161,1380,1093,1891,2060,1877,1825,1806,1896,1854,1748,1613,1789,1795,1939,1963,2123,1704,1864,1693,1862,1706,1461,1488,1608,1367,1419,1516,1347,1475],"KO":[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,1,0,2,0,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,4],"RT":[0.361,0.462,0.42,0.417,0.379,0.583,0.43,0.377,0.449,0.505,0.428,0.591,0.466,0.459,0.595,0.441,0.481,0.462,0.65,0.674,0.668,0.519,0.562,0.547,0.52,0.546,0.474,0.481,0.484,0.457,0.449,0.503,0.432,0.425,0.438,0.422,0.441,0.426,0.395,0.397,0.4,0.385,0.408,0.469,0.416,0.45,0.386,0.414,0.413,0.413,0.395,0.373,0.418,0.386,0.387,0.376,0.386,0.398,0.405,0.406,0.399,0.407,0.395,0.385,0.421,0.397,0.372,0.351,0.39,0.384,0.359,0.401,0.403,0.435,0.395,0.355],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Riesgos":{"SUMOK":200875,"SUMKO":1409,"OK":[50,61,31,55,28,26,5,60,20,0,15,0,15,15,0,0,15,0,15,15,0,15,15,0,13,2,0,30,2,44,146,268,510,1265,2425,2955,3841,4581,5321,5587,5944,6327,5300,5337,5291,5679,5805,3869,3708,6929,7262,6740,6493,6381,6789,6080,5504,6053,5190,5224,4327,2092,1426,1499,2065,2972,3495,3766,4504,4265,4429,5289,4926,4524,3760,4185],"KO":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,5,5,7,5,17,18,24,24,53,36,47,40,41,43,24,26,53,54,62,58,41,46,51,33,29,26,18,10,13,14,16,21,23,48,53,45,49,34,34,43,38,36,43],"RT":[0.065,0.083,0.13,0.707,0.099,0.084,2.82,0.194,0.22,0,0.492,0,0.433,0.161,0,0,0.298,0,0.537,0.446,0,0.52,0.728,0,0.287,0.345,0,0.082,1.316,1.136,0.352,0.576,0.38,0.27,0.256,0.176,0.179,0.136,0.143,0.152,0.126,0.144,0.13,0.154,0.139,0.151,0.134,0.142,0.153,0.166,0.156,0.147,0.137,0.141,0.129,0.142,0.148,0.132,0.128,0.18,0.124,0.159,0.183,0.154,0.147,0.128,0.135,0.141,0.131,0.175,0.141,0.114,0.14,0.139,0.172,0.162],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Particulares":{"SUMOK":709540,"SUMKO":534,"OK":[5794,5284,4816,3580,3018,2283,2006,1486,1186,1311,918,794,607,677,671,600,412,584,454,506,457,672,665,649,932,894,1412,1727,2158,3063,4326,5923,7038,10129,13647,14923,15905,19339,21463,22762,21936,22069,21976,21072,19951,19413,19256,13127,12318,18637,17980,18297,17357,16708,16401,15354,14515,12789,11771,10628,11232,10458,11007,11007,11753,11383,11922,11604,11120,10776,11697,11471,11463,12479,11531,12011],"KO":[7,8,3,1,7,4,3,1,2,4,2,1,3,0,3,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,1,5,4,5,7,6,5,5,11,12,17,14,12,13,20,13,12,9,8,21,13,12,15,17,7,13,11,6,9,9,5,12,11,8,10,8,13,8,8,11,7,8,13,20,11,12],"RT":[0.197,0.241,0.204,0.205,0.247,0.241,0.315,0.302,0.178,0.433,0.505,0.181,0.191,0.183,0.228,0.226,0.219,0.326,0.337,0.535,0.273,0.229,0.267,0.218,0.223,0.202,0.219,0.212,0.241,0.191,0.187,0.169,0.2,0.152,0.158,0.171,0.14,0.159,0.149,0.143,0.156,0.146,0.145,0.137,0.141,0.159,0.142,0.158,0.149,0.136,0.133,0.124,0.16,0.145,0.141,0.139,0.143,0.149,0.126,0.132,0.163,0.192,0.181,0.172,0.186,0.147,0.132,0.167,0.138,0.18,0.153,0.146,0.143,0.166,0.142,0.144],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Particulares BKS3":{"SUMOK":799461,"SUMKO":731,"OK":[6917,6108,5726,4223,3433,2683,2391,1693,1304,1253,921,800,688,693,715,634,493,505,426,418,446,743,735,691,1073,984,1672,1881,2260,3230,4607,6421,7692,11239,14628,16550,18563,20975,23237,25076,24469,24579,24123,23419,22116,21400,21976,14099,13843,21162,20687,21039,19535,18668,18566,17750,16300,14561,13380,12424,12500,11909,12463,12460,13241,12829,13668,13038,12602,12539,13516,13739,13601,14415,13847,14271],"KO":[10,6,8,2,2,2,2,7,1,1,0,0,4,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,3,6,4,8,6,7,7,7,10,14,19,16,17,16,12,18,17,28,23,15,18,18,28,21,23,19,13,11,16,9,15,11,17,10,8,15,23,17,15,8,7,13,15,12,10,18,18,13],"RT":[0.152,0.197,0.156,0.153,0.151,0.199,0.201,0.144,0.149,0.198,0.176,0.34,0.445,0.346,0.406,0.522,0.505,0.405,0.458,0.363,0.297,0.349,0.345,0.216,0.218,0.193,0.2,0.202,0.261,0.525,0.225,0.266,0.17,0.153,0.146,0.148,0.148,0.15,0.154,0.151,0.152,0.155,0.151,0.152,0.142,0.147,0.143,0.142,0.143,0.152,0.148,0.148,0.147,0.151,0.149,0.147,0.141,0.141,0.14,0.144,0.138,0.152,0.141,0.145,0.142,0.144,0.136,0.135,0.136,0.138,0.14,0.144,0.138,0.143,0.143,0.143],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Empresas":{"SUMOK":183051,"SUMKO":658,"OK":[405,389,293,222,254,175,150,182,129,85,78,96,71,85,78,70,70,77,121,77,74,76,102,94,138,149,202,205,371,392,662,958,1269,2478,3425,4178,4458,5982,6565,6905,6723,6242,5983,5989,6005,5467,5452,3187,3855,6037,4980,5874,5682,5283,5166,4975,3949,3239,2753,2354,1884,1819,2065,2305,2645,2640,2954,2835,3068,3017,3068,2997,2682,2849,2599,2639],"KO":[5,0,1,0,6,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,1,5,7,12,9,13,9,15,21,22,22,21,17,24,13,17,20,13,17,23,21,13,22,10,13,19,15,6,11,9,8,5,9,7,21,19,9,5,14,27,7,18,10,13,11,15],"RT":[0.145,0.43,0.128,0.141,0.13,0.138,0.087,0.105,0.093,0.219,0.073,0.203,0.158,0.117,0.178,0.109,0.247,0.259,0.472,0.261,0.375,0.159,0.163,0.21,0.252,0.201,0.222,0.707,0.72,0.303,0.341,0.46,0.195,0.132,0.11,0.102,0.104,0.116,0.121,0.102,0.122,0.128,0.131,0.129,0.105,0.102,0.111,0.111,0.11,0.12,0.101,0.112,0.108,0.106,0.112,0.098,0.105,0.141,0.113,0.096,0.089,0.099,0.114,0.12,0.105,0.112,0.1,0.093,0.099,0.138,0.103,0.095,0.108,0.106,0.112,0.098],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Juzgados":{"SUMOK":333138,"SUMKO":102,"OK":[87,59,33,49,59,73,45,63,67,39,46,31,41,58,21,53,32,31,45,30,41,37,21,68,44,138,211,174,47,62,110,393,710,1359,2868,3914,5416,7705,9541,10509,11443,11403,11296,11986,12718,13056,12457,7840,8102,12545,14057,14422,13735,14547,14024,14292,13172,14054,12174,9538,8052,5539,4256,3502,2772,2498,2164,1823,1420,1154,1533,1671,1602,1420,1399,1142],"KO":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,7,12,13,13,1,2,6,4,3,13,1,8,4,2,0,0,0,1,1,4,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"RT":[0.304,0.211,0.108,0.096,0.119,0.101,0.071,0.088,0.085,0.146,0.098,0.093,0.141,0.087,0.082,0.134,0.488,0.141,0.294,0.413,0.116,0.109,0.091,0.191,0.082,0.142,0.104,0.086,0.088,0.149,0.142,0.15,0.146,0.143,0.113,0.114,0.113,0.11,0.11,0.113,0.15,0.176,0.17,0.178,0.118,0.123,0.12,0.129,0.135,0.162,0.111,0.12,0.13,0.111,0.104,0.107,0.105,0.105,0.104,0.102,0.102,0.107,0.097,0.1,0.093,0.112,0.083,0.111,0.086,0.104,0.105,0.114,0.118,0.095,0.115,0.126],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Broker":{"SUMOK":28224,"SUMKO":84,"OK":[71,74,68,78,32,52,39,17,16,11,16,19,1,9,21,17,6,8,1,6,2,69,41,36,59,34,49,37,16,28,42,18,57,75,70,250,413,1222,987,1045,1109,1110,919,926,873,689,876,426,399,529,576,494,531,462,716,681,527,498,475,386,541,619,451,656,608,831,734,791,715,794,1134,1060,334,242,175,225],"KO":[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,2,9,5,0,2,5,0,1,0,0,4,4,2,1,1,5,1,2,3,0,3,3,1,1,0,3,5,2,3,2,1,0,0,0,3,0],"RT":[0.293,0.716,9.363,0.348,0.363,0.272,0.262,0.213,0.397,1.622,1.954,0.391,4.974,0.728,0.362,1.751,0.501,1.809,0.606,1.114,4.113,0.554,0.418,0.332,0.487,0.244,0.544,0.214,0.23,0.295,0.336,0.242,0.457,0.321,0.457,0.452,0.383,0.439,0.431,0.44,0.469,0.448,0.508,0.463,0.398,0.555,0.46,0.362,0.408,0.426,0.368,0.313,0.316,0.263,0.334,0.318,0.298,0.324,0.493,0.301,0.383,0.345,0.34,0.445,0.313,0.38,0.348,0.324,0.402,0.401,0.476,0.41,0.224,0.22,0.184,0.32],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Sistemas Informacion":{"SUMOK":84657,"SUMKO":282,"OK":[19,19,11,0,6,3,0,6,0,0,6,0,3,3,3,0,3,3,3,3,0,6,3,0,3,6,0,10,70,263,420,872,2529,7961,7513,5454,4559,3310,2970,2652,2740,2444,1807,1600,1960,1825,1666,1188,1299,1429,1684,1668,1291,1213,1438,1347,1324,1385,1355,1377,1344,618,450,347,449,690,972,1157,1200,872,1099,972,1049,969,824,913],"KO":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,2,4,0,1,6,6,0,1,1,12,0,5,3,4,1,22,3,2,4,0,1,0,0,24,101,0,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,2,1,1,33,29,3,1],"RT":[0.437,0.251,0.219,0,2.79,0.3,0,1.323,0,0,1.056,0,1.174,0.659,4.83,0,4.483,4.197,1.64,3.05,0,2.981,0.496,0,0.408,1.601,0,0.662,1.121,1.179,0.325,0.382,0.186,0.222,0.153,0.132,0.133,0.168,0.151,0.15,0.169,0.231,0.16,0.154,0.167,0.182,0.167,0.157,0.152,0.16,0.151,0.192,0.175,0.153,0.199,0.156,0.165,0.158,0.149,0.15,0.136,0.159,0.181,0.205,0.226,0.22,0.253,0.248,0.171,0.212,0.141,0.135,0.153,0.153,0.139,0.152],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Contact Center":{"SUMOK":158998,"SUMKO":216,"OK":[173,44,9,38,63,0,47,6,0,89,19,46,60,11,5,51,2,53,41,13,45,46,11,0,254,65,51,44,9,14,67,52,159,1421,1744,2741,3682,3418,7080,4342,3749,5957,3858,5085,4840,5412,5017,3080,3838,5769,5799,5220,4719,4668,4535,3613,4538,4016,3403,3951,3735,3245,2529,2366,2708,2495,2322,2336,2405,2249,2311,4426,2360,1910,2406,2113],"KO":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,4,2,4,2,4,4,7,4,5,15,12,8,3,5,13,14,12,3,5,7,2,9,5,3,4,0,4,6,1,0,3,8,2,1,7,4,2,3,7,4,4],"RT":[0.083,0.128,0.035,0.131,0.085,0,0.174,0.04,0,0.135,0.035,0.134,0.104,0.061,0.642,0.478,0.046,0.135,0.519,0.524,0.129,0.524,0.256,0,0.255,0.08,0.211,0.145,0.066,0.25,0.092,0.146,0.197,0.181,0.176,0.128,0.15,0.134,0.109,0.128,0.113,0.116,0.12,0.114,0.109,0.112,0.101,0.114,0.102,0.181,0.124,0.119,0.101,0.102,0.108,0.106,0.132,0.105,0.111,0.107,0.104,0.1,0.113,0.09,0.091,0.098,0.094,0.098,0.098,0.103,0.085,0.091,0.102,0.084,0.102,0.087],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Cuentas Personales":{"SUMOK":110273,"SUMKO":73,"OK":[173,135,103,98,141,136,150,102,152,136,108,121,164,101,159,137,130,92,128,102,128,141,103,172,134,134,122,122,122,182,160,244,257,345,498,1170,1843,2355,2500,2503,2646,3045,3609,3141,3232,3720,3167,1809,2320,3944,3653,4718,3772,4470,5061,4953,5029,4992,5265,4342,4523,3027,1672,779,373,548,397,476,557,829,1028,519,420,1041,844,549],"KO":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,3,1,4,1,2,1,0,5,0,1,2,4,0,2,1,0,5,2,7,1,2,6,2,3,1,0,2,0,1,2,0,4,0,0,0,1,1,1],"RT":[0.419,0.439,0.481,2.572,0.854,0.831,0.547,0.426,0.424,1.022,1.369,0.541,0.523,0.528,0.596,0.5,0.563,1.319,2.444,0.764,2.516,0.506,0.478,0.431,0.452,0.437,0.407,0.482,0.415,0.453,0.95,0.845,0.51,1.378,0.528,0.436,0.486,0.357,0.454,0.45,0.373,0.363,0.421,0.401,0.36,0.388,0.414,0.399,0.375,0.388,0.387,0.393,0.383,0.372,0.395,0.394,0.426,0.421,0.517,0.398,0.478,0.581,0.372,0.463,0.346,0.423,0.436,0.429,0.306,0.41,0.336,0.483,0.379,0.365,0.408,0.412],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"Intervinientes":{"SUMOK":6490,"SUMKO":6,"OK":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,43,79,53,1,251,162,173,265,303,205,342,306,241,482,208,124,170,360,56,294,287,276,354,320,97,140,208,207,114,17,38,4,10,23,6,18,47,18,153,0,16,15,4],"KO":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],"RT":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4.772,1.275,1.027,0.304,0.59,0.327,0.484,0.404,0.361,0.657,0.278,0.264,0.283,0.3,0.284,0.341,0.438,0.283,0.4,0.258,0.312,0.365,0.396,0.336,0.363,1.252,0.377,0.311,0.251,0.827,0.927,2.164,0.388,1.25,0.277,1.239,0.253,1.013,0.639,0,1.085,0.283,0.035],"HORAS":["00:00","00:15","00:30","00:45","01:00","01:15","01:30","01:45","02:00","02:15","02:30","02:45","03:00","03:15","03:30","03:45","04:00","04:15","04:30","04:45","05:00","05:15","05:30","05:45","06:00","06:15","06:30","06:45","07:00","07:15","07:30","07:45","08:00","08:15","08:30","08:45","09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30","11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45","15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00","18:15","18:30","18:45"]},"T4B":{"OK":142975,"KO":2293},"PCAS":{"OK":176,"KO":20}}
```

**jQuery Trick**

```
        var OK = [];
        $.each(value.OK, function(tipo, valor) {
                OK = valor;
        });
        // Now if i return OK, it returns me the values... Same for OK, RT ...
```

My question is, I'm missing something on PHP? Because Do the trick on every $datosBS key is a code mess...

I think the problem is that "OK" for example, has subarray with the numbers, and JSON doesn't recognize it like "SUMOK" for example, which is plain number instead an array...

**FULL JQUERY CODE**

```
$.getJSON('test.php?entidad_id=2', function(data) {        
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var pies = {
            name: key,
            type: 'pie',
            data: [],
            center: [100, 80],
            size: 100,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }; 
        var lineas = {
            name: "Valores",
            data: []
        };
        var renderId = "pie-" + key;
        $('#charts').append('<div id="'+ renderId +'" class="pieChart"></div>');
        lineas.data.push(value.OK); // <------ THIS ISN'T WORKING, EVEN IF I DO ([value.OK])
        var OK = [];
        $.each(value.OK, function(tipo, valor) {
                  OK = valor;
        });
        lineas.data.push(OK); // <----- THIS IS WORKING
        pies.data.push(["OK", value.SUMOK], ["KO", value.SUMKO]);
        if(key == "CAM") {
            pies.data.push(["REJ_OTHERS", value.REJ_OTHERS]);
            pies.data.push(["REJ_FORMAT", value.REJ_FORMAT]);
            pies.data.push(["PENDING", value.PENDING]);
        }
        options.series.push(pies, lineas);
        options.chart.renderTo = renderId;
        options.title.text = key;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        pies.data = null; lineas.data = null;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't understand your question, the invalid JSON, the snippet of PHP that has important parts taken out, or the context of that jQuery snippet. Mind giving a little more code and explanation?

Comment: My question is, I'm missing something on PHP? Because Do the trick on every $datosBS key is a code mess... I think the problem is that "OK" for example, has subarray with the numbers, and JSON doesn't recognize it like "SUMOK" for example, which is plain number instead an array...

Comment: Why are we marking this question down?? He's tried some code. Is looking for an alternative way to accomplish this. Sounds like a valid question to me.

Comment: We need to see all of the JSON (what you posted is invalid), and more context to that jQuery and PHP. It is hard to tell what you are doing because what is `value`? What is `value.OK`? To me it looks like an array, and you are just grabbing the last value out of it. What do you need to use that value for? Why are you looping to grab the last value of an array? I don't understand what you goal you want to accomplish is.

Comment: Edited with whole code..

Comment: Which is very helpful, now it looks like you want each key in the object to be a chart. Just so you know `$.each(value.OK, ...)` that you are doing there, does nothing. `tipo` will be the indicies of the array `1, 2, 3, ...` so it will never equal `OK`. But then you never use `OK` array you declared anyway so I don't understand what the problem is here.

Comment: Crap, I forgot to remove that line (was trying something) updated without that lines.

Comment: Doing `lineas.data.push(value.OK)` pushes the `OK` array *as an element* in the `lineas.data` array. What do you think that line should be doing? Entires should be `['title', value]` so what do you expect `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...]` as a data entry to do to your chart?

Comment: If I do `lineas.data.push(["OK", value.OK]);` like on SUMOK or SUMKO, I'm having the same problem because entries into DATA for LINE type are just, the data, the 'title' is given on NAME: 'title' inside SERIES, unlike PIE chart which is given as you said... I just want to insert into DATA [1, 2, 3...] for LINE tipe

Answer (score 0):

OK, data in line charts is 2 values `[x, y]` so the data array is like: `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]`, `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]` doesn't really make sense on a line chart.

If you just want to have the index across the `x` axis and the values along the `y` axis then you can build your array like:

```
$.each(value.OK, function(i, v) {
    lineas.data.push([i, v]);
});
```

and just get rid of:

```
lineas.data.push(value.OK); // <------ THIS ISN'T WORKING, EVEN IF I DO ([value.OK])
var OK = [];
$.each(value.OK, function(tipo, valor) {
    OK = valor;
});
lineas.data.push(OK); // <----- THIS IS WORKING
```

But without knowing what each data point in `OK` corresponds to, that is the best I got.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Urd4V/) of some working code.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

Looks like `HORAS` may be the time that corrosponds to the `OK` element, if that is the case you could do:

```
$.each(value.OK, function(i, v) {
    lineas.data.push([value.HORAS[i], v]);
});
```